# Powershell to create shortcut with quoted target path

Tags: windows, powershell, command, quotes

I try to create a shortcut via a PowerShell script with the following value as a target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& '"C:\Program Files\Test\script.ps1"'"
```

This is my existing script which works but I am not able to get the target path in it as I want.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Program Files\Test\test.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = 
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\Test\tool"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Edit ;) I think this is what you want :

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Program Files\Test\test.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$Shortcut.Arguments = "-Command `"& 'C:\Program Files\Test\script.ps1'`""
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\Test\tool"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

as this is a script and not commands, you can also prefer

```
$Shortcut.Arguments = "-File 'C:\Program Files\Test\script.ps1'"
```

Comment: I created a manual shortcut with the property values then it works. But i want to have a powershell script that creates the correct shortcut for me.

Look Picture to see properties of the working shortcut: https://ibb.co/q1ghjHV

Comment: TargetPath is not a directory its a powershell script

Comment: @HelloWorldIsMyMotto Nope.. the TargetPath is the path to the **executable** (i.e. powershell.exe). The Arguments then hold the parameters to send to this executable.